# Show section of linked image

Tags: inkscape, image-sprite

I'm including a png sprite-sheet in an inkscape file as a linked image. However, I don't want the entire sheet to show, only one of the sprites. I would be even more happy if I could show the animation, but that seems (reasonably) outside the scope of the software. However, there should be some way to include a section of a linked image, right?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do that in Inkscape is to set a "Clip" to the embedded bitmap.

After embedding a bitmap image we can create another object to define the clip path:

[image]

To clip the rectangle out of the bitmap we select both object to then apply *Object > Clip > Set*:

[image]

Any object can be used for clipping. To clip from several objects we need to group them first.

[image]

The clip can be released with *Object > Clip > Release* to reveal the bitmap and the clipping object again.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `Clipping Mask` by creating a path that's the same shape and position of the sprite you want, selecting both it and the sprite, and using `Object > Clip > Set`